# Checkboxes not working in Laravel Nova custom tool

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

So I'm new to Laravel Nova and experimenting with custom tools right now.

In my custom tool I have a checkbox in my tool.vue component. I use the already available vue checkbox component from laravel nova.

```
<checkbox/>
```

The checkbox appears in the form like it should but when I click on it nothing happens. It doesn't get checked and the toggle event from the component doesn't fire.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Checkbox` Vue component that Laravel Nova provides accepts a prop to determine whether the checkbox is checked or not from the parent component, and only emits an event called `input` when the checkbox is clicked so this is why the checkbox doesn't get checked when you click it.
Here's the component located on `nova/resources/js/components/Index/Checkbox.vue`

```html
<template>
    <div class="flex items-center">
        <div
            :disabled="disabled"
            class="checkbox select-none rounded"
            tabindex="0"
            role="checkbox"
            :aria-checked="checked"
            @keydown.prevent.space.enter="toggle"
            @click="toggle"
        >
            <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" :checked="checked" :disabled="disabled" />

            <div class="check">
                <svg
                    class="block"
                    v-if="checked"
                    width="20"
                    height="20"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                >
                    <g id="Page-1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <g id="checkbox-on" fill-rule="nonzero">
                            <g id="b-link" fill="var(--primary)">
                                <rect id="b" width="20" height="20" rx="4" />
                            </g>
                            <path
                                id="Shape"
                                fill="#FFF"
                                d="M7.7 9.3c-.23477048-.3130273-.63054226-.46037132-1.01285927-.37708287-.38231702.08328846-.68093514.38190658-.7642236.7642236C5.83962868 10.0694577 5.9869727 10.4652295 6.3 10.7l2 2c.38884351.3811429 1.01115649.3811429 1.4 0l4-4c.3130273-.23477048.4603713-.63054226.3770829-1.01285927-.0832885-.38231702-.3819066-.68093514-.7642236-.7642236C12.9305423 6.83962868 12.5347705 6.9869727 12.3 7.3L9 10.58l-1.3-1.3v.02z"
                            />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <svg
                    class="block"
                    v-else
                    width="20"
                    height="20"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                >
                    <g id="Page-1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <g id="checkbox-off">
                            <g id="b-link" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                <rect id="b" width="20" height="20" rx="4" />
                            </g>
                            <rect
                                id="Rectangle-path"
                                width="19"
                                height="19"
                                x=".5"
                                y=".5"
                                stroke="#CCD4DB"
                                rx="4"
                            />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>

        <slot />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        disabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        checked: {
            // type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },

    methods: {
        toggle(event) {
            this.$emit('input', !this.checked)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

And so what you need to do is to listen to the click event and pass the data as a prop like so
`ParentComponent.vue`

```html
<template>
  <form>
    <checkbox @input="toggle" :checked="checked"/>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps